# Calculcate zoomlevel for several polylines in mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

For me it is not so clear how to set the right zoom level in mapbox. I have polylines over 5 km and other polylines over 100 km. How can I find out the right zoom level in Android to show the whole poly line in a mapbox map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
val latLngBounds = LatLngBounds.Builder()
                    .include(startTop)
                    .include(endBottom)
                    .build()
mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 50))
```